# Cylindrical coordinates of a ring

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, coordinate-systems

A classical problem for electromagnetism students is the calculation of the electric field on the central axis of a ring. It can be solved in many different ways, but I got stuck with the pure integration method. Let me introduce you the steps written in my book.

The electric field in an arbitrary point $\mathbf{r}$ of the space, is given by the following expression:
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_{L}{\dfrac{\lambda(\mathbf{r'})(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})dl}{\left| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \right|^3}}
$$

Then, in order to solve the integral, it says that in the central axis, the point in which we are calculating the field is given by $\mathbf{r} = z\,\mathbf{u_z}$, which seems ok. However, the part where I get lost is regarding the position of each elemental charge $\lambda(\mathbf{r'})dl$, where the book says that this is $\mathbf{r'} = R\,\mathbf{u_\rho}$, where $R$ is the radius of the ring.

This also looks ok to me, except that not every differential charge is on the same $\varphi$ cylindrical coordinate. So I don't get why $\mathbf{r'}$ has not the form $R\,\mathbf{u_\rho} + \varphi\,\mathbf{u_\varphi}$.

And then, given the previous question, what would be the proper way of expressing a vector $(\rho,\varphi,z)$ as a sum of the basis and why?
$$
\mathbf{v} = \rho\,\mathbf{u_\rho} + \varphi\,\mathbf{u_\varphi} + z\,\mathbf{u_z} \quad \text{or} \quad \mathbf{v} = \rho\,\mathbf{u_\rho} + \rho\varphi\,\mathbf{u_\varphi} + z\,\mathbf{u_z}
$$

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546602

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue before, I guess you are using wikipedia's notion. Notice that $(r-r')=|r-r'|\hat{r}$ and you can reduce the complicated notion to $1/r^2 \hat{r}$. The last question, just google cylinder coordinates, either wolfram or Wikipedia has tons' of explanations. (Wolfram might be very technical, so you might consider Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system ) Just to be clear,$\hat{e}_\varphi,\hat{e}_\rho,\hat{e}_z$ were the orthogonal basis, which express the 3 space completely if you accept $x,y,z$ as a complete expansion. The proper proof comes from Lagrangian's generalized motion.

Answer (score 0):

You will get in trouble if you try to apply angular basis vectors for radial vectors coming out of the origin.

It is best to form cartesian vectors.

$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}'=\left\{R \cos \left(\phi '\right),R \sin \left(\phi
   '\right),0\right\}$

$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}=\{0,0,z\}$

for a ring of charge centered in the $xy$ plane and an observation point on the z axis.

You can still integrate over $d \overset{\rightharpoonup }{l}=R\ \text{d$\phi $} $

Comment: Your last expression must have a unit vector attached to the RHS.